# What prevents an exception from being caught?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a Win32 C++ app developed in VS2005. There is a try {} catch (...) {} wrapped around a block of code, and yet 3 functions deep, when the algorithm breaks down and tries to reference off the end of a std::vector, instead of catching the exception, the program drops into the VS debugger, tells me I have an unhandled win32 exception, and the following is found on the call stack above my function:

```
msvcr80.dll!:inavlid_parameter_noinfo()
msvcr80.dll!:invoke_watson(....)
msvcr80.dll!:_crt_debugger_hook(...)
```

How can I prevent the debugger being called? This occurs at the end of a 30 minute simulation, at which point I lose all my results unless I can catch and log the exception. This and similar try/catch constructs have been working in the past - are there compiler settings which affect this? Help?

Comment: SEH exceptions are not caught by try - catch. I had a similar problem yesterday with improper usage of semaphores http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/seexception.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the delay - unforeseen circumstances - but the real answer appears to be the following.

First, the application is also wrapped in a __try {} __except () {} construct, and uses unhandled exception filtering based on [XCrashReport](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/XCrashReportPt3.aspx). This picks up the non C++ exceptions for the reasons many have pointed out above.

Second, however, as one can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionHandlingInVCPP.aspx) and elsewhere, since CRT 8.0, for security reasons Microsoft bypasses unhandled exception handling on buffer overruns (and certain other situations), and passes the issue directly to Dr Watson.

This is really annoying - I want to know where my buffer overruns are occurring, and why, and to fix them. I also want my program to crash, leave an audit trail, and then be automatically restarted, 24/7. Having MS Visual Studio on the PC seems to mean that Dr Watson will pause and offer me the option of using MSVC to debug the issue. However, until I respond to the dialog box, nothing will happen. Comments on workarounds greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to convert non-C++ exceptions into C++ exceptions. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5.aspx)'s an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Library containers do not check for any logic errors and hence themselves never emit any exceptions.

Specifically, for `std::vector` only method that throws an exception is `std::vector::at()`.
Any Undefined Behavior w.r.t to them will most likely lead your program to crash.

You will need to use Windows' SEH and C++ Exception Handling for catching Windows specific exceptions, which are non C++ standard btw.

Comment: If the Downvoter enlightens the reason for downvoting this it will help us all.

Comment: Most stl methods that need to allocat memory may also throw.

Comment: I don't know about the STL, but the C++ standard library containers generally are at least somewhat exception safe, in the sense of them freeing their memory if something throws an exception (not sure whether that also applies for copy-constructors of stored objects throwing, though).  They don't do much bounds-checking, however.

Comment: You're not using 'exception-safe' in the common meaning of the term. A meaning that is quite straightforward to boot: safety in the presence of exceptions. That's not obviously what you're interested in here.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: OP specifically mentions `when the algorithm breaks down and tries to reference off the end of a std::vector`

Comment: @Anton: Above comment for you as well.

Comment: How did this get any upvotes? Almost every statement in it is false. Firstly, standard library containers *are* designed to be exception safe. There is an [entire chapter in Stroustrup](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_safe.pdf) devoted to this. Secondly, standard library containers *do* throw exceptions (from all of the functions that require allocation of memory). Thirdly, undefined behaviour w.r.t. standard containers will very often *not* result in a crash (in every implementation that I know of).

Comment: @Mankarse: Standard Library containers do not throw any exceptions for their own operations.Ofcourse `new` will throw that doesn't mean containers throw.Do you get an exception for accessing an vctor beyond its bounds,which OP seems to be talking about? You are missing the context of the Q really.

Comment: @Als The only point in your post that I consider incorrect is ``STL containers are not designed to be exception safe.'', and the quote you gave only supports that:  the exception Windows appears to throw (in some weird way) on an out-of-bounds memory access has nothing to do with `std::vector` being exception-safe or -unsafe, as we're not talking about data corruption due to an exception (in fact, we're talking about exactly the opposite).  Even had standard library containers been exception-unsafe, the second statement would still not follow from the first.

Comment: @AntonGolov: Agreed the first statement does not indicate what I wanted to, What I wanted to say,was Standard Library containers do not check for any logic errors and hence themselves never emit any exceptions.I did not edit it but I should.And the OP seems to give an indication here that accessing beyond the bounds of vector would throw an exception,which clearly is not the case.

Comment: @Luc Danton: Agreed I made a mess with the first statement.I didn't mean what it actually was saying then.I mis-used the word `Exception Safety`.I edited it to indicate what I meant to say.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have a `catch(...)` doesn't mean you can catch and recover from all exceptions. Not all exceptions are recoverable.

You problem might be that the first exception that pin points the exact problem is getting obscured by your catch statement

You need to attach the debugger to the program and have it break on all exceptions and fix the code